# Why are my table border look weird in PDF viewers?

Tags: itext7

I generated a table with iText7 (C#):

```
var cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(headers[c]).SetFont(font).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.WHITE).SetFontSize(size).SetBold());
cell.SetBackgroundColor(color);
cell.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);
cell.SetPadding(0);
cell.SetBorder(new SolidBorder(1));
table.AddCell(cell);
```

Document has the table, but on certain scalings, it looks weird on the edges:

[image]

Taking a closer look on the image above:

[image]

If however I change the zoom in the viewer directly, it looks OK:

[image]

How do I get rid of these unnecessary parts from the border?

[image]

I'm attaching here the resulted PDF for reference:

[Download sample PDF](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/C0DPR3Vx#link)

I also noticed that on iText KB pages, there is this kind of behavior:

https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-do-i-change-the-border-color-of-a-pdfpcell

See the red and blue bars' left edges:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any cell before this cell? I mean is this the first cell in that row?

Comment: This is the first cell, yes, and "Header3" is the last one, which also has this effect at its end. Document has only this table, and this table only has one row, with only these 3 cells.

Comment: Can you try setting the border on the table too?

Comment: I tried, but it's not solving this issue unfortunately :(

Comment: Can you share a PDF generated by your code for analysis?

Comment: @mkl: Sure, question is now updated.

Comment: I looked into the example. The numbers in the content are correct, so it's an issue of the viewer. @KJ's answer points in that direction, too.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is not uncommon in PDF or other print drivers where vectors are printed rather than plotter definitions (often called "Dangles". It would be worse if the definition was rounded or square, rather than butt, and join as "mitre" cannot apply, see below). The overlap is intentional (to ensure both lines are inclusive). In a laser drum print that may be desirable overkill, but disastrous for any inkjet or screen. It looks like the cell is not bordered by a box, but using common straight vectors. Again this is often desirable optimisation but not when the weight is not honoured.  Thus it depends if the viewer is using the correct thickness.
All desktop PDF viewers (icluding Chrome and FireFox) I tested showed the lines correctly as clean overlap without "Dangles". Acrobat has a reputation for undesirably thickening or thinning its standard defined lines depending on its user settings.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What kind of program did you use for these screenshots? Indeed, Acrobat shows "wrong", and Chrome, FF shows correctly. If I wish to change *Line caps* for cell borders with iText7, how can I do that?