# IText 8.0.1 How to make table lines flush with edges of table?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am using `iText 8.0.1` and I noticed that when I add a table to my document, many times the lines of the table extend slightly past the edges of the table.

Here is a sample class:

```java
package com.propfinancing.iTextTest;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.HorizontalAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.UnitValue;
import java.io.File;

public class ITextTest {
  /** Run this test */
  public void run() 
  throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\Tmp\\test.pdf");
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);    
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);    
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.LETTER);
    doc.setMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);

    UnitValue[] columnWidths = new UnitValue[7];
    for( int i=0; i<columnWidths.length; i++)
      columnWidths[i] = new UnitValue(30,UnitValue.POINT);
    Table table = new Table(columnWidths);
    table.setFixedLayout();
    for( int i=0; i<49; i++ ) {
      Cell cell = new Cell();
      Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(Integer.toString(i));
      cell.add(paragraph);
      if( i % 2 == 0 )
        cell.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.BLACK);
      cell.setHeight(30);
      cell.setWidth(30);
      cell.setPadding(1);
      table.addCell(cell);
    }
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    doc.add(table);

    doc.close();
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws Exception {
    new ITextTest().run();
  }
}
```

The rendered table looks like this:

[image: output]

It is minor, but the lines of the table extend slightly beyond the edge of the table on the right. It looks messy and does not give a professional appearance to the document.

Here is a sample from my other code:
[image: table]

The lines of the table extend to both the top and right.  And, the top right corner shows both lines overlapping.

I just tried adding a double border using this line:

```
    table.setBorder(new DoubleBorder(4));
```

And the resulting output is even worse:
[image: doubleBorder]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: I am on Windows 11 Home Version 22H2 OS Version 22621.2361. I am using Adobe Acrober Reader Version 2023.006.20320 64-bit.

Comment: Take a look at the example I just added with a double border.  It is notably worse.

Comment: Is your issue probably the same as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75273516/1729265)?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.  If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Hhmmm, would it also be ok to close your question as duplicate of that other question? I don't know what more to say than what K J said in his answer there.