# Attribute Error - Detecting Tables in PDFs with Borb

Tags: python, pdf, borb

I need to detect tables in pdf files so I can create field forms in empty cells.

To test the functionality of borb to achieve that goal, I attempted to use the author's [example](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples/blob/master/chapter_007/README_for_leanpub.md#71-extracting-tables-from-a-pdf) as a guide.

My code:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf.page.page import Page
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit.table.table_detection_by_lines import TableDetectionByLines as TDBL
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.annotation.square_annotation import SquareAnnotation
from borb.pdf.canvas.color.color import HexColor, X11Color

def main(infile, outfile):

    # get doc
    t = TDBL()
    doc = None
    with open(infile, "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle, [t])
    assert doc is not None

    # get page
    p = doc.get_page(0)

    # get Tables
    for r in t.get_table_bounding_boxes():
        r = r.grow(Decimal(5))
        p.add_annotation(SquareAnnotation(r, stroke_color=X11Color("Green")))

    with open(outfile, "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    infile = "Parameter.pdf"
    outfile = "ParameterOut.pdf"
    main(infile, outfile)
```

I used my own pdf file here: ["Parameter.pdf"](https://github.com/mattjkenney/portfolio/blob/main/Parameter.pdf).

---

When I run the program, I receive this error:

```
# etc..
r = r.grow(Decimal(5))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'grow'
```

---

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`

### 0. About `borb`

Please check the signature of `get_table_bounding_boxes`:

```py
    def get_table_bounding_boxes(self) -> typing.Dict[int, typing.List[Rectangle]]:
        """
        This function returns the bounding boxes (as Rectangle objects) of each Table
        that was recognized on the given page.
        """
```

In short, this method returns a `dict`, and not a `list[Rectangle]`.

That's what's going wrong in your code. You are trying to call `grow` on something that is not a `Rectangle`.

### 1. About your PDF

**disclaimer2:** I checked your document. I may be wrong. But this is my interpretation of what is happening.

Your PDF is doing something strange. At the lowest possible level, a PDF document uses postscript operators to draw things (lines, curves, images, text) on a page. These postscript instructions are typically stored compressed in the PDF.

I decompressed your PDF. It contains the following instructions:

```
q
72.504 706.06 77.4 13.464 re
W* n
 /Span <</MCID 0/Lang (en-US)>> BDC q
72.504 706.06 77.4 13.464 re
W* n
BT
/F1 11.04 Tf
1 0 0 1 77.664 709.06 Tm
/GS10 gs
0 g
/GS11 gs
0 G
[<0057>17<0102018C>24<01020175>6<011E>9<019A>9<011E018C>] TJ
ET
Q
```

Now for some explanation (you can follow along in the PDF spec, **Annex A - Operator Summary**. A copy of the spec can be found in the borb repository):

`q`: Save graphics state
`re`: Append rectangle to path
`W*`: Set clipping path using even-odd rule
`n`: End path without filling or stroking

So, your document is instructing the PDF viewer to add a rectangle to the path, but then never issues an instruction to actually fill or stroke that path.

Just to drive that point home, this is the explanation the spec gives for the `re` operator:

> Append a rectangle to the current path as a complete
> subpath, with lower-left corner (x, y) and dimensions width
> and height in user space. The operation
> x y width height re
> is equivalent to
> x y m
> ( x + width ) y l
> ( x + width ) ( y + height ) l
> x ( y + height ) l
> h

`l`: Append a straight line segment from the current point to the
point (x, y). The new current point shall be (x, y).

`h`: Close the current subpath by appending a straight line
segment from the current point to the starting point of the
subpath. If the current subpath is already closed, h shall do
nothing.
This operator terminates the current subpath. Appending
another segment to the current path shall begin a new
subpath, even if the new segment begins at the endpoint
reached by the h operation.

And the PDF spec clearly differentiates between building a path (and closing it) and actually stroking or filling it.

In **Table 60 - Path-Painting Operators** you can find the evidence:

`S`: Stroke the path.
`s`: Close and stroke the path. This operator shall have the same effect as the sequence h S.

Comment: Thanks @Joris. I edited the line to `for r in t.get_table_bounding_boxes().values():`. This way, I would iterate through the `list[Rectangle]` classes. Now, the error reads: `'list' object has no attribute 'grow'`. Additionally, when I add `print(r)` to the loop operations, I get only an empty list object: `[]`.

Comment: Again, look at the return type. You should expect to get a list of Rectangle objects. The reason for that is there may be multiple tables on the page (hence returning a list). If `borb` does not detect a table on a given page, you will get an empty list.

Comment: I finally got your results with some edits [here](https://github.com/mattjkenney/portfolio/blob/main/pdf/table_detector.py). Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the PDF file I created from a Word document. It's only results in an empty list - not detecting any tables. Do you have any suggestions to help with table detection?

Comment: Hi @JorisSchellekens. I meant to tag you in the comment above for a response.

Comment: I changed the repo link to [here](https://github.com/mattjkenney/shared_repo/blob/main/pdf/table_detector.py)

Comment: I did a quick check of your input file. TDBL (as the name implies) tries to figure out the presence of tables by looking at the line rendering instructions inside a PDF. For some reason, no line-rendering events are triggered in your PDF. I'll have to dig deeper to figure out why.

Comment: @Joris Please look at the bottom of the page content stream, there you find the instructions that draw the table border lines (by filling thin rectangles). Adobe Acrobat has some quirks, but they are not so wild that it draws line without cause.

Comment: @mkl I checked out the last parts of the page content stream. I assume you're referring to the use of the `f*` operator? According to the spec this is supposed to fill a path, not stroke it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Filling a thin rectangle effectively draws a line.

Comment: To explain why some PDF producers prefer to draw lines as thin rectangles: Using actual line stroking commands you sometimes get weird display artifacts in some PDF viewers, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75273516/1729265) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77219504/1729265). Using filled thin rectangles, though, you don't.

Comment: How wonderfully atrocious. In order to be able to process these kinds of tables I would need to: implement the `f*` operator, and I'd need some kind of heuristic to say "we are using a thin rectangle to draw a line, let's fire a LineRenderEvent". That's currently out of scope. But I may get back to this in the future.

Comment: Thank you @Joris and @mkl. I found the Bytes stream (I think) at `list(page["Contents"].values())[3]` assuming `page` is a `borb.pdf.page.page.Page` object. Could I simply edit the stream to include stroking the path? I made several attempts already with no success. For example, I tried replacing `b'n'` with `b's'`, among others.